# how is the jwt interceptor logic

Tags: angular, logic

I`m confused: 
Look this, I will explain how I understand the refresh of the token trough with the jwt interceptor.

1) The request has a token, and it is sent to the server.

2) The server responds, with a 400 bad request.

3) And the interceptor handles the HTTP responds doing in the first try: calling the refresh token to the server.

4) the refresh token is old, so the server, say a 400 again.

5) **What is going to happen now?. Will the server send another refresh service?** How can I get out of the "bucle".

```
// src/app/auth/jwt.interceptor.ts

// ...
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';

export class JwtInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(public auth: AuthService) {}

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    return next.handle(req).do((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
      if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
        // do stuff with response if you want
      }
    }, (err: any) => {
      if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse {
        if (err.status === 401) {
          // redirect to the login route
          // or show a modal
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your token is old you should be expiring the session on the server before sending the response to the client. If you are using express session you can just call destroy then send the 401. In your interceptor you can also destroy any aspects of session you have on the client before performing your auth redirect as well.